# Label id is changing, how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this asp:label in my page and what I want is to change the text from time to time.  But label id is changing from page to page when i run the code. its been appended with "ctl00_bh_" something...

how to fix this?

here are my code snippets.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onLoad", "DisplaySessionTimeout()", true);
}

<asp:Label ID="lblSessionTime" runat="server" />

function DisplaySessionTimeout() {
    document.getElementById("lblSessionTime").innerHTML = "updating text here";
    sessionTimeout = sessionTimeout - 1;
    if (sessionTimeout >= 0)
        window.setTimeout("DisplaySessionTimeout()", 1000);
    else
    {
        alert("Your current Session is over.");
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your Javascript you are trying to access the server side control, you need to use the ClientID, try

```
document.getElementById("<%= lblSessionTime.ClientID%>").innerHTML ="updating text here";
```

Or [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) in aspx page if you are using .Net framework 4 or higher

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSessionTime" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: @user1120260, you are welcome, you may accept the answer if it is appropriate see How does [accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)